# Program isn't giving me the desired outcome

Tags: java

My program is only allowing me to **enter 3 characters** into the array and not *five*. Why is that so?

```
import java.io.*;
public class Prog{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char c[] = new char[5];

        for(int i=0;i<-4;i++){
          c[i]= (char) br.read();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How are you entering the chars?.. one by one by pressing enter?

Comment: remove the minus from your loop first

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for [BufferedReader#read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()):

> Reads a single character

In other words, this will read in each character one by one.  The reason it appears that you can only enter three characters is because you are pressing enter after each character:

```
first character
ENTER
second character
ENTER
third character
```

Use `readLine()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    char c[] = new char[5];

    for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
        c[i] = br.readLine().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

This approach will read in one line at a time, in this case a line being defined as a single character followed by a newline.  If you enter more than one character in a given line input, then only the first one will be used.